# Pandas series to CFFI pointer

Tags: python, pandas, python-cffi

I am trying to interop between Python and Rust code using CFFI module. I want to pass a Pandas series data pointer through C interface. However I don't know how the underlying series data is laid out. I can make it work by calling `series.to_numpy()` but is it possible to pass a pointer directly to Pandas array without having to copy the data into Numpy array?

See the following example:

```py
import cffi

import pandas as pd

series = pd.Series((1.0, 2.0, 3.0))

ffi = cffi.FFI()
ffi.cdef('void main(const double *values, uint32_t length);')
lib = ffi.dlopen('./target/debug/libpython_rust.so')

# pointer = ffi.cast('double *', series.array)  # <-- is it possible to make it work?
pointer = ffi.cast('double *', series.to_numpy().ctypes.data)  # <-- works but we are making a copy

lib.main(pointer, series.size)
```